# Favorite button in recyclerview, no internal data stored no firebase or parse methods, click in Adapter

Tags: android, database, adapter

Hello im having a lot of problems with this.recycler item...

[image]

it has been very very difficult for me to manage the click in the favorite item since i have to manage the click from the adapter.

This is my main class..

```
public class CarroNuevoFragment extends Fragment {


private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;


RecyclerView recyclerView;
public CarroNuevoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carro_nuevo, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);


    layoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    final List<Automoviles> allItems = new ArrayList<Automoviles>();


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Automoviles");
    query.whereEqualTo("esNuevo", true);
    query.include("Marca");
    query.include("Referencia");
    query.include("Sucursal");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> carroList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + carroList.size() + " scores");

                for (ParseObject carros : carroList) {
                    ParseFile file = carros.getParseFile("Imagen");
                    ParseObject marca = carros.getParseObject("Marca");
                    ParseObject ref = carros.getParseObject("Referencia");
                    ParseObject sucursal = carros.getParseObject("Sucursal");
                    if(file !=null){
                        allItems.add(new Automoviles(
                                carros.getObjectId(),
                                marca.getString("Nombre"),
                                carros.getString("Placa"),
                                ref.getString("NombreRef"),
                                carros.getString("Color"),
                                carros.getBoolean("Transmicion"),
                                carros.getParseFile("Imagen").getUrl(),
                                carros.getInt("Modelo"),
                                carros.getInt("Precio"),
                                carros.getString("Chasis"),
                                carros.getInt("Kilometraje"),
                                carros.getString("Motor"),
                                carros.getInt("Year"),
                                sucursal.getString("Nombre"),
                                carros.getBoolean("esNuevo"),
                                carros.getString("isFavorite")));
                    }else {
                        allItems.add(new Automoviles(
                                carros.getObjectId(),
                                marca.getString("Nombre"),
                                carros.getString("Placa"),
                                ref.getString("NombreRef"),
                                carros.getString("Color"),
                                carros.getBoolean("Transmicion"),
                                Config.resourceImage,
                                carros.getInt("Modelo"),
                                carros.getInt("Precio"),
                                carros.getString("Chasis"),
                                carros.getInt("Kilometraje"),
                                carros.getString("Motor"),
                                carros.getInt("Year"),
                                sucursal.getString("Nombre"),
                                carros.getBoolean("esNuevo"),
                                carros.getString("isFavorite")
                        )
                        );
                    }


                }

                CarrosViewAdapter adapter = new CarrosViewAdapter(getContext(),allItems);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {

                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });


    return  view;
}


}
```

This is my adapter...

```
public class CarrosViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private List<Automoviles> automovilesList;
    private Context context;
    ParseObject entity = new ParseObject("Automoviles");

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;


public CarrosViewAdapter(Context context, List<Automoviles> itemList) {
    this.automovilesList = itemList;
    this.context = context;

}

public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_carros, null);
    RecyclerViewHolder rcv = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.txtTitulo.setText(automovilesList.get(position).getMarca());
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(automovilesList.get(position).getImagen())
            .into(holder.imgCarro);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Automoviles model = automovilesList.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CarroDetalleActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("ListaVehiculos", model);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    String isFavorite = automovilesList.get(position).getIsFavorite();

    if (isFavorite.equals("true")) {
        holder.imagenFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
    } else {
        holder.imagenFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
    }

    holder.imagenFavorito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String isFavorite = automovilesList.get(position).getIsFavorite();

            String objectID = automovilesList.get(position).getObjectId();

            if (isFavorite.equals("false")) {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Automoviles");

                query.getInBackground(objectID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

                        object.put("isFavorite", "true");
                        holder.imagenFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Favorito guardado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "No guardo" + " " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }


                            }


                        });


                    }
                });


            } else {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Automoviles");
                query.getInBackground(objectID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                        object.put("isFavorite", "false");
                        holder.imagenFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);

                        object.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {

                                }

                            }
                        });


                    }
                });

                holder.imagenFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
            }


        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.automovilesList.size();
}

}
```

This is my Viewholder class...

```
class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
ImageView imgCarro;
TextView txtTitulo;
ImageView imagenFavorito;
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    imgCarro = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCarro);
    txtTitulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txttitulo);
    imagenFavorito=itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorito_item_inventarios);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View view, ViewModel viewModel);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

I am using Back4app as server and i have the data column as isFavorite contains String true or false that is correctly implemented by the way.
When i click on the favorite it turns red but when i click it again nothing happens im thinking it because the adapter already runned. Some may say to notify the adapter but where in the adapter class. Or if the answer is another please give a very good answer! .

Answer (score 0):

You have used `notifyDataSetChanged();` method in `if` block of `onClickListener` in adaptor. But you haven't put it in else block. Try puting `notifyDataSetChanged();` in last line of `onClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

In your viewholder make these changes -

```
ImageView imgCarro;
TextView txtTitulo;
ImageView imagenFavorito;
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    rootView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemRootView);

    imgCarro = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCarro);
    txtTitulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txttitulo);
    imagenFavorito=itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorito_item_inventarios);

    imagenFavorito.setOnClickListener(this);
    rootView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    void onFavoritoClick(View view, int position);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()){
         case R.id.itemRootView: {
              //Action code for Item click
              itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition())                 //With Adapter position you can retrive which item was clicked 
         }
         case R.id.favorito_item_inventarios: {
              //Action code for Favorito click
              itemClickListener.onFavoritoClick(v, getAdapterPosition())
         }
     }
}
```

this is my xml....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/itemRootView"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:elevation="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCarro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txttitulo"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/side_nav_bar" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/scrim" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttitulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Nombre carro"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/favorito_item_inventarios"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="335dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="199dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_favorite_border_white_18dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener in your activity to get item & fav click and use clicked items for further actions.

Comment: Hello in order to test i have a question please. What do you do with the rootview for what do you cast it . The other question is that in my tree i have 1)Framelayout 2)Cardview 3)RelativeLayout 4).... so im having trouble identifying the root component i will update my xml design . Thanx

Comment: Root view of your recyclerview's itemview which is in this case is FrameLayout